# How can I control the pan, tilt, lighting, and other features on a Logitech QuickCam Orbit/Sphere AF webcam?

Tags: webcam, camera, logitech

When the **Logitech QuickCam Orbit/Sphere AF webcam** is in use on Windows, a little window pops up enabling pan, tilt, zoom, and lighting control. This applet works outside of the program currently capturing video.

**Is there a similar, full featured control program available for Linux?**

I did find the CLI `uvcdynctrl` and a simple python/tk GUI program [pyuvcdyncrtl.py](https://gist.github.com/1441019), which wraps around it, but pyuvcdyncrtl.py can't control the dynamic lighting, zoom, or other features.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try 'guvcview' for pan/tilt control.

Comment: This is sufficient, but I'm looking for a more elaborate control that what it provides.

Answer (score 7):

## Command-line use

To see a complete list of the possible settings for your webcam, do

```
uvcdynctrl -cv -d /dev/video2
```

Notice you need to specify the device to use, default=`video0`, but can also be `video1`, `video2`... In my computer for example is video2.

### Pan camera

To the left:

```
uvcdynctrl -d /dev/video2 -s 'Pan (relative)' 1
```

To the right:

```
uvcdynctrl -d /dev/video2 -s 'Pan (relative)' -- -
```

To reset pan:

```
uvcdynctrl -d /dev/video2 -s 'Pan Reset' 0
```

And so on...

## Graphical use

With viewer

```
guvcview
```

Without viewer of during use (with cheese for example)

```
guvcview -o
```